# How to draw a zoomable Cantor set from a Python list?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

> I've written a Python script f(n) which produces a list of the whole, then the thirds, then ninths, then 27ths, etc. of a line segment.  How do I convert this into a graph - ideally one I can zoom in and out of and navigate?

I want to draw the first line, then the thirds underneath, then the ninths under those, and the 27ths below that and so on like the familiar way the Cantor set is constructed.

f labels the segments of the interval that remain at each stage of the Cantor set construction, with some value (let's say it numbers them for argument's sake) and it labels all the removed segments with a zero, labelled in the following format:

[row-number, element_number, label]

where label is some parameter for each segment, let's say for now it numbers the removed parts beginning with 1 and labels all removed parts zero.

so it outputs:

f(0)=[[0,0,1]]

f(1)=[[0,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,2,3]]

f(3)=[[0,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,2,3],[2,0,4],[2,1,0],[2,2,5],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,6],[2,7,0],[2,8,7]]

etc.

So to be clear, to graph the first n rows I need not use f(x less than n) as f(n) is sufficient to list the segments in every row.

All necessary data's there as we can read off the line number l and from that can position its height as well as deduce the length of the segment as 1/3^l, and we have the element_number e of the element so we can place it at position e/3^l, and we have the label to place at its centre e/(2*3^(l-1))

I've installed networkx, mathplotlib, and I could also export a gexf but I'm struggling to find a way (for a noob programmer) to draw these labelled bars or segments.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would this answer help? https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/90899-write-a-function-that-produces-a-plot-for-the-cantor-set

Comment: @BoboDarph not sure; I have the set, it's the zoomable, navigable rendering engine I'm struggling to realise.

Comment: The problem is pretty unclear. It seems you just need to plot a line from one poin to the next.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest do you get that f(1) outputs row-number 0, item-number 0, label 1?  And that f(2) outputs that followed by the three segments of length one third that go on the 2nd line, identified as row 1, elements 1,2,3 and labelled 2,0,3 in turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the "labels" at all. But a cantor plot is rather easily produced by recursively walking the levels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line = [0,1]
depth = 5

def divide(line, level=0):
    plt.plot(line,[level,level], color="k", lw=5, solid_capstyle="butt")
    if level < depth:
        s = np.linspace(line[0],line[1],4)
        divide(s[:2], level+1)
        divide(s[2:], level+1)

divide(line)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Labeling the lines is in this far not straight forward here because the recursive placement of the lines is in a different order than the desired labeling. One solve this by placing a label for each line and later on sort the labels; then giving each the number from the sorted list.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line = [0,1]
depth = 5

labels=[]
def divide(line, level=0):
    plt.plot(line,[level,level], color="k", lw=5, solid_capstyle="butt")
    label = plt.annotate("",xy=(np.mean(line),level), xytext=(0,5),
                         textcoords="offset points", ha="center", color="crimson")
    labels.append(label)
    if level < depth:
        s = np.linspace(line[0],line[1],4)
        divide(s[:2], level+1)
        divide(s[2:], level+1)

divide(line)

labels.sort(key=lambda x: x.xy[::-1])
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    label.set_text(i+1)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Note that the smaller the lines, the less readable the text is. So labeling the lower, small lines makes only sense when zooming in I guess.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Easy for you.  Hard for me! I'm just looking to number the bars - 1 at the top, 2,3 next, then 4,5,6,7 next etc.

Comment: By "label the bars" you mean literally putting a text label inside the plot?

Comment: I added a solution for that. Not sure in how far this is really useful, as labels quickly tend to overlap.

Comment: Fab, thanks. I can learn from this and your code. I'll see if I can translate this into a zoomable graph built in d3.